# How do I create a .bat to logoff a specific user from your pc?

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch, batch-file

Running remote desktops that are acting as specific users on Win7x64.

The main username I'm using is `Server`.
And the rest are as follows

- `hh1`
- `hh2`
- `hh3`
- etc.

Basically these handheld remote desktop connections sometimes lock up and I want to be able to have the user run a batch file to force logoff specific users from the pc.

I tried using the command `shutdown -r -l -f -m \\server\hh1`

but that command only seems to work logging off specific computers and not users.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Use `logoff.exe`.

Comment: Just asked a friend of mine who does stuff like this -- he said that you can't (shouldn't?) do this with a `.bat` file, and that he would write a "Powershell" script, or some such thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `qwinsta` and `rwinsta` commands to query and disconnect users. Unfortunately, I'm unable to test the remote feature of the commands due to security settings at my current location. But, as per this [Tips and Tricks page at Tech Talkz](http://www.techtalkz.com/blog/tips-n-tricks/how-to-view-disconnect-remote-desktop-sessions-from-commandline.html) explains, you can definitely do it locally (and remotely, I just can't check if it works as explained)

From a command prompt, perform the following.

Query the connected users:

```
qwinsta
```

The command will return 6 columns. We are interested on the `SESSIONNAME`, `USERNAME` and `ID` columns. The `SESSIONNAME` you're interested in will contain the string `rdp-tcp#` followed by a number. Match that to the `USERNAME` you want to disconnect, and note the corresponding `ID` column. On to the next step.

Disconnect the user:

```
rwinsta <ID>
```

Where `<ID>` is the session ID of the user whom you would like to disconnect.

This works for locally connected RDP sessions (e.g. from the computer you want do disconnect the remote user) but hopefully a remote implementation will work better at your location.

Hope that helps.